# Lambda function has fewer invocations than expected

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a Lambda setup that goes like this:

1. A starting lambda called `getOrders()` connects to an external API, fetches the list of orders for the day, and for each other, publishes an SNS event to the topic.
2. The SNS topic is being subscribed to by an SQS queue.
3. In turn, the queue acts as a trigger for another lambda function called `storeOrder()`.
4. The lambda `storeOrder()` receives the single order data, connects to a MongoDB instance hosted on Atlas, and stores the order there.

I would expect the number of orders sent from `getOrders()` lambda to show up in the final MongoDB database, but that's not the case. Before I provide more details, let me make it clear that it is a new account with zero traffic, which means there are no other lambda functions running. Also, the number of orders we're dealing with 400 to 1200, which varies from one day to another. As I'm testing this, the number is around 450.

So, what I see is that if I run the `getOrders()` lambda, the MongoDB has only 230 of the 450 orders. I initially thought it was Atlas acting up, but the monitoring tab in `storeOrder()` shows only 230 invocations.

Another test I ran was to send 50 order events in a batch, with a delay of 5 seconds added (by `await`ing a `setTimeout` function). In this case, the results are much better, as some 380 orders show up in the MongoDB database. And once in a while, I see more orders than I sent (probably the SQS's at-least-once delivery at work) but running the test again with same settings doesn't yield the same result, so I just wanted to mention this.

This forces me to conclude that there is a bottleneck somewhere that is simply dropping messages. The candidates are SNS and SQS, but I have no idea how to check the total number of events/messages received by them, etc.

Has someone faced similar situations in AWS Lambda? What might be causing this? Are there any settings that I might have screwed up, resulting in this behavior? I have no idea how to solve this!

Comment: Presumably `getOrders` is a typo of `readOrders` or vice-versa? What does CloudWatch Logs for this Lambda function show? You're going to have to do some debugging to make sure that if it reads N orders then it publishes all N to the SNS topic. Make sure that part is correct, before heading to the next part of the workflow.

Comment: @jarmod Yes, that was a typo, thanks! I fixed it. The logs of `readOrders()` show what's expected: a few invocations, graphs of total execution times, etc. I see now errors or failures. "make sure that if it reads N orders then it publishes all N to the SNS topic" -- I agree that I should start with this. Any advice on how to go about this?

Comment: Well, it’s your code reading the orders and publishing to SNS so you can add debug logs to ensure that the code is behaving as expected. If you get an OK response from an SNS API call for example then that’s evidence that it succeeded. Enhance logging in your Lambdas and review it afterwards. And I mean the actual low-level logs, not the high-level metrics.

Comment: Is storeOrder() receiving single orders or batches of orders from SNS? Any chance that you are receiving a batch but mistakenly processing it as a single order, thus ignoring a number of orders?

Comment: @jarmod It's single orders, and not batches, simply because there's a loop in `readOrders()` that shoots off events one by one.

Comment: And by low-level logging, do you mean something like log a line for every event published and count them afterward (hopefully, this counting can be done in CloudWatch)?

Comment: @ankush981 It is probably worth setting up dead letter queues for the sns and sqs components to see if anything is dropping out from there.

Comment: And here's something interesting I found: if I resend the request multiple times, the percentage rises and reaches 100%. I mean, for 633 orders, here's the number of orders in the db after consecutive invocations of `getOrders()`: 430, 608, 629, 633.

Comment: @KMo I have a DLQ for SQS, which is empty all the time. Didn't know we can set up a DLQ for SNS too. Will do that.

Comment: @ankush981 It was literally announced yesterday. https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/11/amazon-sns-adds-support-for-dead-letter-queues-dlq/

Comment: @KMo Lol! Okay, I did that but I don't see any messages in any DLQs. Out of 633, only 417 orders were stored in the DB. By the way, what do you make of the fact that if I repeat this process enough times, all orders will be stored in DB?

Comment: @ankush981 if you are losing a percentage of orders everytime, it would make sense that you are not losing the same records everytime, therefore if you run the batch enough times you'll eventually get all of them through

Comment: The most obvious reason for the symptoms that you are seeing is that your storeOrder code is failing to recognize that is is being sent a batch of orders, and is simply processing one order and ignoring the others. Sending orders one by one to SNS is not a guarantee that they arrive at your ultimate storeOrder Lambda function one-by-one if they go via SQS. They could be batched. Check the length of the Messages list that your storeOrder Lambda receives.

Comment: @jarmod If you see the description of my setup, there indeed is an SQS between the SNS and Lambda. That said, I just tested what you said and it worked! Looks like the lambda function is receiving 1, 2, or 3 events at a time. Can't thank you enough as I wasted the last two days on this. :( Please add this as an answer and I'll accept it. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The symptoms suggest that your `storeOrder` code is is being sent a batch of orders, but it is only processing the first order in the batch and is dropping/ignoring the others.

Sending orders one by one to SNS is not a guarantee that they will arrive at your ultimate `storeOrder` Lambda function one-by-one if they go via SQS. They could be batched. Check the length of the `Messages` list that your `storeOrder` Lambda receives.

Note that SNS will trigger Lambda with just one message, but SQS and DynamoDB can trigger Lambda with a batch of messages. You should always iterate over the list of messages instead of assuming that there will be just one message in that list.